# VK API | Свой шаблон поста

Tags: vkontakte-api, vk-mini-apps

Можно ли при использовании VK API каким-то образом добавить свою собственную кнопку в уже существующий шаблон поста? Пример можно увидеть ниже.

P.s: хочу написать сервис для vk, который будет добавлять, допустим, кнопку просмотра геолокации, которую будут видеть все подписчики сообщества.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Это сделать невозможно. Внешний вид постов регулирует сам ВК

Comment: А каким тогда образом, например, расширения для браузеров - добавляют кнопку скачать музыку на странице "музыки" в вк и т.д